# Trying to send 2+ objects in http.put body, backend return empty body

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6

I'm trying to send two objects, one of them is a myFile object which has the info about a file uploaded (name, description, author, etc), the other object is a FormData which has a file selected by the user.

i've tried this

```
 uploadFile(fileObject:myFile,formData:FormData,project:Project){
    let obj = {
      fileObj: fileObject,
      formDat: formData
    };
    let url = URL_SERVICE + 'projects/'+proyect._id+'/files?token='+this.token;
    return this.http.put(url,obj).pipe( map( (res:any) => {
      return res;
    }));}
```

and this put request, but in both cases im getting an empty body:

```
return this.http.put(url,{fileObejct,formData}).pipe( map( (res:any) => {
          return res;
```

This is a simple route just to print the body

```
app.put('/:id/files',cors({origin:"http://localhost:4200"}),[mwAuth.checkToken],(req,res) =>{
    var idProject = req.params._id;
    var body = req.body;
    res.status(200).json({
        ok:true,
        body: body

    });     
});
```

Comment: `formDat: formData` is this the problem?

Comment: i'm not getting any info about the Form Data in server response

Comment: I am saying that you misspelt key name. at one place its formDat and another place its formData

Comment: formDat it's just the key shown in response from server

Comment: what does the network tab in your browser show? Did you remember subscribe? Why are you having pointless pipe to map?

Comment: in network tab i can't see anything as the size as the file, i'm calling uploadFile() from a service in my component ts and i'm using console.log to see the response from the subscribe